# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths side effects?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an UITableView filled with UITableViewCell that contain a checkmark.

[image]

When I click on a cell, if it was marked it becomes unmarked and vice-versa.

[image]

So far so good. Now I want to update the first cell every time I click on any other cell (assume the first cell is peculiar). I modified my code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath (see below) and it works correctly except that I get the following undesired behavior on the cell that I click :

[image]

As you can see the white line on the top of the cell has disappeared...

Here is what my code looks like for the (I guess) critical functions :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [myLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    bool isChecked = false;
    if ([currentValues[indexPath.row] boolValue]) {
        isChecked = true;
    }
    cell.accessoryType =  isChecked ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    bool isChecked = false;
    if ([currentValues[indexPath.row] boolValue]) {
        isChecked = false;
        currentValues[indexPath.row] = [NSInteger numberWithBool:false];

        // below is the part of code that causes trouble

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        // end of problematic code
    }

    else {
        isChecked = true;
        currentValues[indexPath.row] = [NSInteger numberWithBool:true];
        // similarly...
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    } 
    cell.accessoryType = isChecked ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark :UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

**NB** If I reload the whole table, then I don't have this problem. But I feel that it may be worth for me understanding what is happening there.

**NB2** I tried with and without the calls to [self.tableView beginUpdates] and [self.tableView endUpdates] but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will go with little bit changes like,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    bool isChecked = false;
    if ([currentValues[indexPath.row] boolValue]) {
        isChecked = false;
        currentValues[indexPath.row] = [NSInteger numberWithBool:false];

        // below is the part of code that causes trouble
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]; 
        //MYCHANGES
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        // end of problematic code
    }

    else {
        isChecked = true;
        currentValues[indexPath.row] = [NSInteger numberWithBool:true];
        // similarly...
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]; 
        //MYCHANGES
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    } 
    cell.accessoryType = isChecked ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark :UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you so much !!  Any idea what is happening when you don't deselect the cell ? Why does this cause the white line to disappear ?

Comment: You can say, this is bug from Apple, I don't have much idea, but whenever A row/cell is selected and if you perform reload cell, it removes the separator, till you reload full tableview, which is not proper solution every time.